# CROSSTAB does not properly display the data - wrong sorting or something

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

Hope you can help me out - drives me nuts:

Using the following code I get the following correct output:

```
SELECT dow.day, h.hour, count(created_at)
--  FROM 
--  CROSSTAB($$ SELECT h.hour, dow.day, count(created_at)::INT
    FROM (values('Mon'),('Tue'),('Wed'),('Thu'),('Fri'),('Sat'),('Sun')) AS dow(day)
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,23) as h(hour)
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_state_change VSC ON to_char(VSC.state_changed_at, 'Dy')=dow.day AND extract(hour from VSC.state_changed_at)=h.hour
    WHERE to_state_id = 17 
        AND location_id = 4 
        AND date_trunc('day', state_changed_at) >= '2020-02-17'
        AND date_trunc('day', state_changed_at) <= '2020-02-23'
        AND h.hour = 7
    GROUP BY dow.day,h.hour
    ORDER BY h.hour, dow.day
--           $$)
--  AS d(Hour int, "Mon" int,"Tue" int,"Wed" int,"Thu" int,"Fri" int,"Sat" int,"Sun" int);
```

[First results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMKZJ.png)

But once I try to run it into a CROSSTAB the data does not make sense anymore and I cant find the solution.

```
SELECT *
-- dow.day, h.hour, count(created_at)
    FROM 
    CROSSTAB($$ SELECT h.hour, dow.day, count(created_at)::INT
    FROM (values('Mon'),('Tue'),('Wed'),('Thu'),('Fri'),('Sat'),('Sun')) AS dow(day)
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,23) as h(hour)
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_state_change VSC ON to_char(VSC.state_changed_at, 'Dy')=dow.day AND extract(hour from VSC.state_changed_at)=h.hour
    WHERE to_state_id = 17 
        AND location_id = 4 
        AND date_trunc('day', state_changed_at) >= '2020-02-17'
        AND date_trunc('day', state_changed_at) <= '2020-02-23'
        AND h.hour = 7
    GROUP BY dow.day,h.hour
    ORDER BY h.hour, dow.day
             $$)
    AS d(Hour int, "Mon" int,"Tue" int,"Wed" int,"Thu" int,"Fri" int,"Sat" int,"Sun" int);
```

[Second results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHy41.png)

Comment: You need to provide which platform you're using, because CROSSTAB is not an standard SQL syntax.

Comment: I use PgAdmin 4 v4